# Clear mixin for Less not working using When Guard

Tags: css, less

I am trying to create a simple less mixins for clear so I have:

```
.clear {

  &:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  } // :after

}

.clear(@float) when (@float = "left", @float = "right") {
  clear: @float;
}
```

Basically I want to clear both when I use ".clear" or ".clear(both)" and the second one when I use .clear("left") or ".clear("right").

How can I do this?

Thank You,
Miguel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**#1** The most straightforward way is to use [`default`](http://lesscss.org/functions/#misc-functions-default) mixin guard:

```css
.clear(...) when (default()) {
    &:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
        clear: both;
    }
}

.clear(@float) when (@float = left), (@float = right) {
    clear: @float;
}
```

**#2** Or:

```css
.clear(...) when (default()) {
    &:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
        clear: both;
    }
}

.clear(left)  {clear: left}
.clear(right) {clear: right}
```

**#3** Or even more clean/optimal in this case (and also old Less versions compatible) [Pattern Matching](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature-pattern-matching) for all variant:

```css
.clear() {
    &:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
        clear: both;
    }
}

.clear(both)  {.clear()}
.clear(left)  {clear: left}
.clear(right) {clear: right}
```

### ---

> ... and the second one when I use `.clear("left")` or `".clear("right")`.

Don't use quotes there, correct usage would be:

```css
.clear;
.clear();
.clear(both);
.clear(left);
.clear(right);
```